# How to use buttons in Excel to edit one of several possible cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am working on an Excel 2016 document and I have a table of names and points, as well as a default value, formatted like this:

```
Name   Default   Points
Bill     50        10            Jim <-- This is a cell outside of the table,
Jim      16        32                   that displays the name that is "selected."
Sam       5         8
```

Currently, I have three buttons (one to increment the number in the Points column, one to decrement the number, and one to reset to the value in the Default column) set up for each name using this basic VBA code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("C3").Value = Range("C3").Value + 1   <-- for the increment button
End Sub
                      [OR]
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Range("C3").Value = Range("C3").Value - 1   <-- for the decrement button
End Sub
                      [OR]
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Range("C3").Value = Range("B3").Value       <-- for the reset button
End Sub
```

Is there a way to introduce just three buttons, and set them up so that each button could work for the point values of any one name from the list?

For example, if I have Jim selected (like in the table example above), the button will recognize that Jim is selected, find the points value associated with Jim (32), and edit that value)?

Comment: Look into the `Range.Find` function.. you can then find the cell in your Name column that corresponds with the "selected" cell from which you can pull the row and thus target your increment/decrement/default routine.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. Selected cell text is in "G3"
2. Won't be more than 34 names in the "Name" column

Furthermore, we assume you assign the appropriate `Sub` to the buttons.

```
Sub IncrementButton_Click()
    TakeAction "Increment"
End Sub
Sub DecrementButton_Click()
    TakeAction "Decrement"
End Sub
Sub ResetButton_Click()
    TakeAction "Reset"
End Sub

Sub TakeAction(ByVal action As String)

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Set foundCell = Range("a2", "a35").Find(Cells(3, 7).Text)
    If Not (foundCell Is Nothing) Then
        r = foundCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Couldn't find the current selection."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case LCase(action)
        Case "increment"
            Cells(r, 3) = Cells(r, 3) + 1
        Case "decrement"
            Cells(r, 3) = Cells(r, 3) - 1
        Case "reset"
            Cells(r, 3) = Cells(r, 2)
    End Select

End Sub
```